# What are the versions of AFCI?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, afci

Leviton had an AFCI that said "AFCI 2.0" and one now says "AFCI 3.0".  Any idea what the difference is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on limited info from Leviton, I would conclude that the 2.0 and 3.0 are simply receptacle updates, similar to model years for cars.  The part number isn't changing but they made some trivial changes to the design.  They are not promoting any major differences between the versions.

Specifically, the 2.0 and 3.0 versions are both advertised with SmartlockPro features.

If you were to order these online from a retailer, there's likely no way to know which "version" they have in stock.  They could switch to 4.0 before you even expect it.

Answer (score 7):

from Leviton:  " Thank you for contacting Leviton Tech Support. The difference between AFCI 2.0 and 3.0 is the 3.0 has more arc signatures built-in/programmed. The 3.0 would be less likely to false trip in some instances."